# compare set time with current time python

Tags: python

I have a @interval check that can run def timecheck(): every 10 second and I need to compare current time/weekday with a set time/weekday.

```
 @interval(10)
 def timecheck():
 <<< compare current time and weekday with time day ie 09:45  Mon,Tues,Wed,Thur,Fri>>>
 <<<if true then run premkt>>

  def premkt(bot):
  bot.msg('#optiontrader',"((( US MARKET OPEN IN 15 Minutes )))")
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You are expected to show some research effort. Can you show us what have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: What is the actual question? Are you having a problem with the code below? What does it do unexpectedly? Does it have a traceback? What is that traceback? These are things we need to help answer your question.

Comment: actually I am a newbie to python and what you see is what I have thus far. I just need to compare current time and weekday with a set time day ie 09:45  Mon,Tues,Wed,Thur,Fri and if true the run premkt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the builtin [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module to do this.

Note that `datetime.weekday` returns an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.

You might want to add a check somewhere that `premkt` isn't called multiple times in the same minute.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

if now.weekday() < 5 and now.hour == 9 and now.minute == 45:
    # it's 9:45 on a weekday, do stuff
    premkt(bot)
```

Comment: if now.weekday() < 5 and now.hour == 9 and now.minute == 45:                                                                                                                     
When testing with python I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax for the 'if'

Comment: It works just fine here, with both python 2.7 and 3.3. Check your indentation and the line before the if.

Comment: Thanks.. all is well now. Thank you very very much for your help